# Aggregating a dataframe of weekly (7 day) data to monthly in R

Tags: r, time-series, lapply, zoo

This question is related to this post of [aggregating weekly(7 day) data to monthly in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15932576/aggregating-weekly-7-day-data-to-monthly-in-r). I basically want to run same function but also across columns. But I couldn't figure it out. My data is as follows:

```
  start      end              X1      X2     X3 ...
1 2004-01-04 2004-01-10       54      63     10 ...
2 2004-01-11 2004-01-17       56      49     11 ...
3 2004-01-18 2004-01-24       46      39     11 ...
4 2004-01-25 2004-01-31       45      37     10 ...
5 2004-02-01 2004-02-07       39      31     11 ...
6 2004-02-08 2004-02-14       41      30     11 ...
```

I have tried the followings:

I try to apply to the whole data frame at once by not specifying a column in `to.day`. `df[i,]`run into error and below `df`comes back to all `NA` values.

> ```
> to.day<-function(i) with(df,zoo(df,seq(start[i],end[i],"day")))
> z.day<-do.call(c,lapply(1:nrow(df),to.day))
> z.day_df<-data.frame(z.day)
> z.mon<-aggregate(z.day,as.yearmon,mean)
> ```

Thank you.

Comment: The to.day function is wrong.  Look at how it was done in the link.

Comment: Yeah in the link it's specified as one column i.e.X1[i], but here I want to specify a column by not using the name so I can later loop it across other columns, so I used df[i,3], which also works but when I changed to df[i,4] and X2[i] (which refer to same column), I still got monthly value for X1 and df[,3]. So I failed to change column in to.day there.

Comment: Thanks Grothendieck! I actually tried df[i,3:ncol(df)], but it returned all NAs. However when I try df[i,3:5] it worked. So I think previously maybe just one column was causing the problem of NAs.